# jaxb2-maven-plugin 2.2 not generating package structure as per jaxb:package tag

Tags: java, maven, binding, jaxb, jaxb2-maven-plugin

We are using jaxb2-maven-plugin 1.3 with binding files having jaxb:package tag so that plugin can generate proper directory structure. Now we want to update it to version 2.2. Although it is generating classes package structure is not as per the configured jaxb:package tag

Comment: what is generated and what is expected ?

Comment: I am jaxb file where I have tag <jaxb:schemaBindings>
   <jaxb:package name="com.aPkg.bPkg" />
  </jaxb:schemaBindings> but the packages are genrated different than com.cPkg which is namespace mentioned into the schema file

Comment: pls add schema and pom.xml that explains better. It could be configuration issue that we cannot find from your statements.